# Por que o href não funciona como desejado?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Estou utilizando um theme especial na minha aplicação que possui uma funcionalidade de chat. Para abrir este chat o template utiliza a seguinte referência `href="#offchat-canvas"` para um elemento da minha view. Este chat é um *offcanvas* que possui o histórico de mensagens. Porém esta chamada é feita com elementos estáticos no exemplo. Quando tentei inserir elementos dinâmicos utilizando o `ng-repeat` o href apenas altera a minha url `url/s#/offcanvas-chat`. O href com valores estáticos abre um *offcanvas* lateral sem alterar a URL.

Já tentei o sanitize para inserir o html.

Já tentei métodos de target (`data-target="_self"`).

Já tentei utilizar o `ng-href="{{elementId}}"` com `$scope.elementId = '#offcanvas'`

Já tentei alterar para o modo HTML5.

gostaria de saber se estou esquecendo algo importante. Sou novo em angularJS e em aplicações WEB. Caso necessite de mais detalhes, posso responder.

**Editado**

Código estático:

```html
<li class="tile divider-full-bleed">
  <div class="tile-content">
    <div class="tile-text"><strong>Estático</strong></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="tile">
  <a class="tile-content ink-reaction" ng-click="createChat(users[3])" href="#offcanvas-chat" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="tile-icon">
      <img src="http://acdc.sandro.in/{{users[3].avatar}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile-text">
      Teste Chat Dinâmico {{users[3].nome}}
      <small>123-123-3210</small>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Código Dinâmico:

```html
<li class="tile divider-full-bleed">
  <div class="tile-content">
    <div class="tile-text"><strong>(NG) {{letter}}</strong></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="tile" ng-repeat="user in getUsersByLetter(letter)">
  <a class="tile-content ink-reaction" ng-click="createChat(user)" href="#offcanvas-chat" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-backdrop="false" >
    <div class="tile-icon">
      <img src="http://acdc.sandro.in/{{user.avatar}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile-text">
      (NG) Teste Chat Dinâmico {{user.nome}}
      <small>123-123-3210</small>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código HTML do seu repeater? Acho que fica mais fácil ajudar. Geralmente é o sanitize que fa isso sim. Mas também pode estar faltando usar o `ng-href`

Comment: Editei minha pergunta. Tanto o sanitize quanto o ng-href não funcionaram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meu Amigo, muito provavelmente a sua template está verificando o HTML antes do AngularJS compilar, ou seja, sugiro que voce coloque o inicializador do seu Chat dentro de um `timeout` de alguns milisegundos que garanta que o AngularJS renderizou `$digest` o HTML...

Outra forma de resolver o problema seria colocar uma chamada nesse plugin sempre que a função `getUsersByLetter(letter)` for invocada... não é muito recomendado fazer chamados de Jquery/Plugins de dentr ode controllers o que levaria a voce criar uma diretiva para esse comportamento, mas para tornar a sua solução mais simples, faça isso no controller mesmo... por ex:

```
 $scope.getUsersByLetter = function(letter) {
      $timeout(function(){ //refresh no seu plugin da template },100)
 }
```

Comment: A fonte do problema está correta! Ontem mexendo eu consegui resolver. Meu template possui 2 _offcanvas_. Um para mostrar os usuários online (que funcionava normal) e outro que aparecia quando você clicava dentro desse primeiro _offcanvas_. Como este segundo fugia de dentro do contexto do AngularJS eu precisava inicializar novamente a função que executava o _offcanvas_. Minha solução foi chamar dentro do meu app o método que inicializava meus _offcanvas_. `materialadmin.AppOffcanvas.initialize();`.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você abre um único `off-canvas` para apenas depois popular eles.
Acho que o seu problema é só uma questão de ordem. Pois você está deixando ele dentro do `ng-repeat`, ou seja, você está criando múltiplos `off-canvas` e tentando abrir com uma única chamada.

Veja que ele está dentro do `ng-repeat` :

```
<li class="tile" ng-repeat="user in getUsersByLetter(letter)">
  <a class="tile-content ink-reaction" ng-click="createChat(user)" href="#offcanvas-chat" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-backdrop="false" >
    //... resto do código...
```

Tente mover ele para fora do `ng-repeat` e veja se funciona. Ou como alternativa, tento aplicar um `id` para cada `href`, mais ou menos assim:

```
<li class="tile" ng-repeat="user in getUsersByLetter(letter)">
  <a class="tile-content ink-reaction" ng-click="createChat(user)" href="#offcanvas{{user.id}}-chat" data-toggle="offcanvas{{user.id}}" data-backdrop="false" >
    //... resto do código...
```

O código vai depender de como você está manipulando o `canvas`, mas acho que com isso você consegue se guiar melhor.

Comment: Entendi. Mas é ideia é essa mesmo Celsom. Possuo apenas um único offcanvas. No meu controller possuo apenas um `$scope.chattingUser`. Essa função `createChar(user)` atualiza este _scope_ que é enviado para o meu _offcanvas_. A resposta do Rogério foi correta. Ontem mesmo consegui resolver. Porém de uma forma diferente, que vou explicar com um comentário na resposta dele. Mas Agradeço a ajuda!!